# How to make a link placed inside an IFRAME open in the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a JS game that's running inside an IFRAME, which is scaleable and all that fancy stuff.

The game contains a link to the next page, and the link works brilliantly.

Problems is that the link is opening inside the IFRAME and not the parent window. I need the flow to continue in the parent window and not the iframe.

the way the next page is linked in the IFRAME is like this:

LINK_BUTTON="data.php",

That's the only piece of code pointing out the link. 
To my regret I can't FIDDLE this because of disclosure issues.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is LINK_BUTTON a javascript variable?

Comment: Yes it is.

It's the first line next to the "var".

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_parent"` on your link.

```
<a target="_parent" href="data.php">link</a>
```

Or from Javascript

```
window.top.open("data.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

 I'm afraid the link is not an HTML tag but is instead embedded into the JS as a "LINK_BUTTON"

This is making this particulair problem quite a bitch because it would have been much easier as a HTML link.

Comment: Try `window.top.open(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the target attribute. This will force the link to open in the parent.

```
<a target="_parent" href="data.php">Next</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

 I'm afraid the link is not an HTML tag but is instead embedded into the JS as a "LINK_BUTTON"

This is making this particulair problem quite a bitch because it would have been much easier as a HTML link.

Comment: How is the HTML generated then? Are you using a framework to do that?

Comment: The JS is the only thing containing an actual link, it's not presented as an HREF but as a LINK_BUTTON var

Comment: Ok, but at some point it must be rendered onto the page. How does that happen? What are you using to create this game? The LINK_BUTTON var must be used somewhere to create a link.

Comment: I see! I didn't think about it like that. I am not sure how it's rendered, I can't seem to find the element with firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute. To open in the current top window (top frame):

`<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">Link Text</a>`

Or to open in a new window:

`<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Link Text</a>`

There's also _parent for the parent window (not necessarily the top) and _self for the current window (the default).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, as given above, is really to add `target="_parent"` attribute to your anchor (link).

The catch here is that you'll have to find in the javascript code where the LINK_BUTTON is used to generate the rendered link, and then in the code, add the target attribute.

Comment: Indeed! That's exactly what I'm looking for and I just can't find it.

Comment: Try opening the IFRAME's source code and text search for the LINK_BUTTON variable. If it's not there, look for these type of tags: `<script src="somefile.js"></script>`, open them and, again, text search for your variable.

Comment: I found the LINK_BUTTON attribute, it only contains the LINK 

Like this:

LINK_BUTTON="gegevens.php",

Im not sure how to add a target to it now.

Comment: You have to fiddle with javascript code. It could look like something (or not)  like this: `"<a href=" + LINK_BUTTON + ">next page</a>`".